# LINQ select new KeyValuePair<T,List<T2>>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a LINQ query like this:
Two lists linked through Entity Framework Navigation Properties (Both Entities have a Many-To-Many Relationship)

I'd like to convert this:

```
var query = (from a in listA 
             from b in a.ListB
             select new {T1=a, T2=b}
```

To something like this:

```
var query = (from a in listA
             from b in a.ListB
             select new KeyValuePair<T1,List<T2>>{ T1=a , T2=b})
```

The first query produces a list of items like this: {(a,x), (a,y), (a,z), (b,x) ...}

The intent of the second query is to merge the results into items with their own lists.

Results would look like this:

{(a,List with items x,y,z), (b, List with item x) ...}

I'd appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Edit: thanks to Stijn for correcting my answer.

It looks like `a` already contains a list of the related `b` items, so wouldn't this work?

```
var query = (from a in listA
             select new{ T1 = a, T2 = a.ListB });
```

You can also convert the query to a Dictionary:

```
var asDictionary = query.ToDictionary(item => item.T1, item => item.T2);
```

Comment: Oh, good point... I missed that it was `a.ListB` and not just `listB`. :P

Comment: @minitech I had to look at the code twice to notice.  Hopefully it is just a quick example and is not in charge of firing missiles!  The other thing to note is that multiple `from` statements go through every combination, sort of like nested `foreach` statements.

Comment: This snippet is completely wrong. What are `T1` and `T2` in your object initialiser? It should be `Key` and `Value`. Still, that wouldn't work either, because `Key` and `Value` are read-only.

Comment: @Stijn Interesting point.  We actually don't need the KeyValuePair at all and could just do `new {T1 = a, T2 = a.List}`, correct?

Comment: Correct. You can then create a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` if desired, with `.ToDictionary(item => item.T1, item => item.T2)`. If you can update your answer, I'll change the downvote to an upvote.